# ¿Como activar un <li> dependiendo de la pagina donde me encuentre con JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo JS:

```
var theme_list_open = false;

    var aurl = window.location.href; // Get the absolute url
    $('li a').filter(function() { 
        $(this).prop('href') === aurl;
        if (theme_list_open == true) {
            $("ul li ul").hide();
            theme_list_open = false
        } else {
            $("ul li ul").show();
            theme_list_open = true
        }
        return
    }).parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Pero no se que esta pasando, ya que cuando entro a un link lo que hace es que todas las `child-list` me las activa, es decir:

```
Usuario (link Principal)
ingresar usuario (link hija)
actualizar usuario (link hija)
borrar usuario (link hija)

Departamento (link Principal)
ingresar dpto (link hija)
actualizar dpto (link hija)
borrar dpto (link hija)
```

sucede que al hacer `click` en cualquier `link` inmediatamente se desplieguen todos los `links` que dependen de un `link padre`...

espero haberme hecho entender y agradeceria la colaboración.

Answer (score 1):

es mas sencillo hacerlo por css

```
.current{
   background-color: #000;
}
```

y a la que necesitas que se le haga el cambio le pones la clase ya sea por medio de jquery o por el back que tengas.

Answer (score 0):

Trata con el siguiente codigo:

```
var theme_list_open = false;
var aurl = window.location.href; // Get the absolute url
$('li a').filter(function() { 
    if ($(this).prop('href') === aurl) {
     if (theme_list_open == true) {
         $(this).find("ul li ul").hide();
         theme_list_open = false
     } else {
         $(this).find("ul li ul").show();
         theme_list_open = true
     }
    }
    return
}).parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Hola @Carlos E. Mendoza S. gracias por el interes, he probado el codigo pero lastimosamente no me ha funcionado.

Comment: tal vez si publicas el código html podría ayudar mejor